# Generate a spreadsheet with multiple worksheets from Microsoft C#

Tags: c#, excel

Existing C# code created in Visual Studio generates a complete report in the form of an Excel workbook with the report formatted in a single worksheet in that workbook. Need to create a workbook with a variable number of worksheets with the same report format but with different data values on each worksheet.

Current C# program creates a workbook with a single worksheet using the following code:

```
  oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));  //Get a new workbook.
  oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;     // add a worksheet
```

Tried using a "FOR" loop using the index of the FOR loop to name the worksheets. How can the worksheet reference ("oSheet") be indexed in the loop? Adding the FOR loop "ii" index to the oSheet name give a compiler error:

```
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));  //Get a new workbook.
for (int ii = count; ii > 0; ii--) 
{
    oSheet[ii] = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;     // add a worksheet
```

Comment: What are you using for this export?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you need to add worksheets to the existing workbook your code creates, or create another new workbook? Do you understand the difference between a workbook and a worksheet?

Comment: Stop adding random sentences to the comments, and [edit] your question to make it clear and specific what you're asking. You can find the [edit] link in the lower left corner of your question, right under the tags.